# Restricting qlineedit by file type

Tags: qt

How is it possible to have `qlineedit->settext()` to accept file of type .ma only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the string to be of the format `<filename>.ma` in the `QLineEdit`.

If that's the case, you can use

```
void QLineEdit::setValidator ( const QValidator * v )
```

Also, [`QRegExpValidator`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qregexpvalidator.html) can validate for specific strings.

I am not well versed with RegExp but I guess `QRegExp rx("*.ma");` as an Regular Expression will be fine for your case.

Hope it helps...

Comment: you might need `rx.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::Wildcard);`, or you use a real regulare expression instead of a wildcard syntax.